# Como receber um array de dados do meu storage do ionic

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic, typescript

Preciso enviar alguns dados para meu php que tratará eles e enviará para meu banco de dados do cpanel.

No meu código, consigo salvar corretamente os dados que quero (imagem, latitude e longitude) no storage do ionic e também consigo trazer-los para minha pagina.

Minha função de post para meu php também está funcionando corretamente pois já testei enviar com dados estáticos.

Meu problema está na hora de trazer os dados já salvos no storage e realizar o mesmo envio.

Como posso acessar o storage e trazer esses dados para a função postData enviar-los?

A função que faz esse envio se chama postData.

Segue o código:

Script que pega/salva todos os dados e salva no banco:

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Camera, CameraOptions } from '@ionic-native/camera/ngx';
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';
import { Geolocation } from '@ionic-native/geolocation/ngx';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class PhotoService {
   lat: any;
   long: any;
   public photos: Photo[] = [];
 
 constructor(private geolocation: Geolocation, private camera: Camera, private storage: Storage) { }

 takePicture() {
     this.geolocation.getCurrentPosition().then((resp) => {
        this.lat = resp.coords.latitude;
        this.long = resp.coords.longitude;
       }).catch((error) => {
        console.log('Error getting location page2', error);
     });

     const options: CameraOptions = {
       quality: 100,
       destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
       encodingType: this.camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
       mediaType: this.camera.MediaType.PICTURE
     };

  this.camera.getPicture(options).then((imageData) => {
   // Add new photo to gallery
   this.photos.unshift({
    latitude: this.lat,
    longitude: this.long,
    data: 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + imageData
   });

   // Save all photos for later viewing
   this.storage.set('photos', this.photos);
   console.log("Latitude2: "+this.lat);
   console.log("Longitude2: "+this.long);
  }, (err) => {
     // Handle error
   console.log("Camera issue: " + err);
  });
   }

 loadSaved() {
   this.storage.get('photos').then((photos) => {
     this.photos = photos || [];
   });
 }

 dataSave() {
   this.storage.get('photos').then((photos) => {
    this.photos = photos || [];
     return (this.photos);
   });
 }

 clear(){
  this.storage.clear();
  location.reload();
 }
}

class Photo {
  data: any;
  latitude: any;
  longitude: any;
}
```

Html:

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-title>
      SEMEC <img id='logo' src="../assets/img/logo-prefeitura.png">
    </ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>
  <ion-grid>
    <ion-row>
      <ion-col size="6" *ngFor="let photo of photoService.photos">
        <img [src]="photo.data" />
        <p>Latitude: {{photo.latitude}}</p>
        <p>Longitude: {{photo.longitude}}</p>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
  </ion-grid>

  <ion-fab vertical="bottom" horizontal="center" slot="fixed">
  <ion-fab-button (click)="photoService.takePicture()">
    <ion-icon name="camera"></ion-icon>
    </ion-fab-button>
  </ion-fab>

  <button ion-button (click)="photoService.clear()"><ion-icon name="trash"></ion-icon>Apagar fotos</button>
  <button ion-button (click)="getRequest()"><ion-icon name="get"></ion-icon>Get</button>
  <button ion-button (click)="postData()"><ion-icon name="post"></ion-icon>Post</button>

  {{requestObject}}
  {{dataFromService}}

</ion-content>
```

Script para chamar as funções de tirar foto e enviar os dados via http

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { PhotoService } from '../services/photo.service';
import { HTTP } from '@ionic-native/http/ngx';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders} from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-tab2',
  templateUrl: 'tab2.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['tab2.page.scss']
})

export class Tab2Page {
  requestObject: any = null;
  dataFromService:any = "";
  itens:any = [];

  constructor(public photoService: PhotoService, public http: HttpClient, private httpget: HTTP) { }
  
  ngOnInit() {
    this.photoService.loadSaved();
  }

  getRequest(){
  this.httpget.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1', {}, {}).then( res => this.requestObject = res.data).catch( err => this.requestObject = err);
  }

  postData(){
   this.itens = this.photoService.dataSave();
   console.log(this.itens);
   var link = 'http://semecmaceio.com/maceio-geo/json/maceiogeoreports.php';
  var myData = {image: this.itens.data, latitude: this.itens.latitude, longitude: this.itens.longitude, accuracy: 0};
  
  this.http.post(link, myData, {headers: new HttpHeaders({"Content-Type":"application/json"})})
  .subscribe(dataFromService => {
    this.dataFromService = JSON.stringify(dataFromService);
  });
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Já encontrei o erro.

O problema estava na forma como eu estava retornando o valor.

Deveria ser

```
dataSave() {
  this.storage.get('photos').then((photos) => {
    this.photos = photos || [];
  });
  return (this.photos);
}
```

E não:

```
dataSave() {
  this.storage.get('photos').then((photos) => {
    this.photos = photos || [];
    return (this.photos);
  });
}
```